# Tkinter Frame not appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I wrote a short piece of code in tkinter in python to see if I could make a frame appear in my window. Here is the code below:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Window")
root.state("zoomed")
root.config(bg="white")

winHeight = int(root.winfo_height())
winWidth = int(root.winfo_width())

controlFrame = Frame(root, bg="red")
controlFrame.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

I created one full-sized window with a background colour of white. The frame inside it is supposed to be red. However, when I run this code, I do not see any red. I am sure I packed it and everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd love to help you out on this one...

There's just a slight detail that you might not notice right now but the frame, in fact, is present in the window, but it's too small to see. By this I mean you haven't specified the height and width of the frame that you have placed in the window. Here's the fixed version:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Window")
root.state("zoomed")
root.config(bg="white")

winHeight = int(root.winfo_height())
winWidth = int(root.winfo_width())

controlFrame = Frame(root, bg="red", height = 700, width = 700)
controlFrame.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

What this will do is just set the height and width of the frame to 700px, so you will get a square frame of red colour.

I hope this answer was satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried doing this but it’s still not working I will send the code

Comment: controlFrame = Frame(root, width=700, height=700, bg="red")
    controlFrame.pack()
```

Comment: Is there a way I can place it in a certain position

Comment: @HarmanPunchi You can try using `place(...)` to control its position and size, for example `controlFrame.place(x=100, y=100, width=400, height=200)`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple, you don't have any other widget in your frame, it's empty for now, so its size is 0 pixel (or 1, I don't remember). That's why you don't see it in your window.

Comment: I tried to add a label to it but it is not appearing